# Can Radare2 emulate null pointer exceptions and others?

Tags: radare2, emulation

I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck with Radare2's configuration variables, `esil.exectrap`, `esil.iotrap`, and `esil.nonull` while *emulating*?

```
xor eax, eax
mov eax, dword [eax] <-
```

From what I can tell, if I set all of the variables to `true` (specifically `esil.nonull`), I should expect an exception in the above code and for it to stop executing, or see the eflags change right? Well that's not what happens and execution continues.

There is also the `cmd.esil.trap` variable, amongst a few similar ones, that allow me to execute a command when a trap happens. I've tried commands such as `echo trap` but again nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong or missing something here? Do I need to configure another variable to make this work? Is this only available in debug mode?